# Warnings in Objective c with method call

Tags: objective-c, pointers, methods, casting, warnings

I think this will be pretty simply answered, I'm just stumped on how to get rid of these warnings.

I'm getting *'DebugZoneLayer' may not respond to '-getGID:tileKind'* and *Initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast* when I do this method call:

```
int blocksCollidableGID  = [debugZoneLayer getGID:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:(NSString*)tileCoord] tileKind:@"blocksCollidable"];
```

Which I tried all different combinations of casting those types of values.

In DebugZoneLayer.h I have:

```
-(int) getGID:(CGPoint)tileCoord withTileKind:(NSString*)tileKind;
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you actually #import'ed the DebugZoneLayer.h ? Also, the first argument is of type `CGPoint`, but you're doing something very wrong: you pass a pointer to `NSValue` instead, and in the call to `valueWithCGPoint:`, which expects a CGPoint, you are casting something to a pointer to `NSString` ? Double ouch.

Comment: NSValue is an ObjC object and CGPoint is a struct.

Comment: Yes I have imported DebugZoneLayer.h. I expected what I was doing was very ouch, yes.

Comment: So.. I still haven't settled on an answer here. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no casting that's needed for either tileCoord or tileKind

int blocksCollidableGID  = [debugZoneLayer getGID:tileCoord withTileKind:@"blocksCollidable"];

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it should be withTileKind instead of tileKind.

Edit: I mean this line ;-)

```
int blocksCollidableGID  = [debugZoneLayer getGID:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:(NSString*)tileCoord] withTileKind:@"blocksCollidable"];
```

Edit:

so now you got rid of the warning. Now the compiler finds some other errors, like others already mentioned. Since you seem stuck at this point, I'll try to guess what to do.

You mentioned, that tileCoord is a CGPoint. So there is absolutely no need to cast or convert it anyway. Try this line of code:

```
int blocksCollidableGID  = [debugZoneLayer getGID:tileCoord withTileKind:@"blocksCollidable"];
```

and see if there are other errors.

Comment: Even after changing it to CGPoint, I get the error CGPoint is not an Objective-C class name or alias. What I have written is int blocksCollidableGID  = [debugZoneLayer getGID:[CGPoint valueWithCGPoint:(NSString*)tileCoord] withTileKind:@"blocksCollidable"];

Comment: Read the other answers, you have also other errors in your code which reveal when you solve the warning problem as I told you.

Comment: Okay I realize now that line you wrote was not trying to show the correct way to write it.  I really don't know what to do here. Same error with int blocksCollidableGID  = [debugZoneLayer getGID:[CGPoint valueWithCGPoint:tileCoord] withTileKind:@"blocksCollidable"];

Comment: Yes, I only pointed out how to remove the warning, for which you asked. After that, the method is found by the compiler but you get errors from other mistakes you made.

Comment: You posted something that gets rid of warnings but now gives errors?

Comment: Removing the warning just revealed your other mistakes. *Read the other answers* which point out all the stuff you did wrong beside the fact that you called a method which didn't exist.

Comment: I have my method -(int)  getGID:(CGPoint)tileCoord withTileKind:(NSString*)tileKind which exists and I saw kperryua post and posted my revisions of calling that method.

Comment: I edited my answer to correct the other mistakes. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Also the first parameter should not be an NSValue, it should be a CGPoint.

Answer (score 1):

septi is correct about the selector typo, but there seems to be some additional problems as well.

- `-valueWithCGPoint:` takes, well, a `CGPoint`. The cast to `(NSString *)` is incorrect. What is `tileCoord`?
- The first parameter is declared to take a `CGPoint`, not an `NSValue`, so the boxing doesn't seem necessary in the first place.

Comment: I should of mentioned that... tileCoord is a CGPoint.

Comment: So if boxing isn't necessary, am I on the write track for writing it like this?   int blocksCollidableGID  = [debugZoneLayer getGID:[CGPoint valueWithCGPoint:tileCoord] withTileKind:@"blocksCollidable"];
And how would you do that without boxing?

Comment: Try this: `[debugZoneLayer getGID:tileCoord withTileKind:@"blocksCollidable"];`. The 'boxing' I spoke of is the `-valueWithCGPoint:` bit. If the method takes a `CGPoint`, and you have a `CGPoint`, then just pass it, instead of boxing it up in an `NSValue`.